# Bluemix. Monitoring and Analytics. Response time not correct

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js application that I'm monitoring using "Monitoring and Analytics" service.

I'm using a jMeter (or SOAP UI) to do a load test against my node.js application. The average response time I'm getting with the load test tools is 900ms but in the Monitoring and Analytics graph it shows 111ms.

On the other hand the throughput is correct.(110tx/sec on jMeter, 6600tx/min bluemix)

Am I misunderstanding something in the bluemix graphs? Why this 800ms difference?

---

EDIT: The 800ms overhead could be caused because of my computer / tools / network but while I'm running the test with 100 concurrent threads in my local environment, in other location (network / place) one single invocation to the service takes also 900ms, if my environment is the cause in other location the response time should be a bit more of 111ms not 900ms so I think it is not related to my infrastructure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Monitoring and Analytics service measures the time it takes for the Node.js application to build the HTTP response from the point that the request is handled.

Here's a simple HelloWorld example annotated with the measurement points:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    // TIMER STARTS
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World');
    // TIMER ENDS
}).listen(port, host);
```

This means that two (potentially major) latencies are not measured:

1. The network latency

   ie. the time taken for the network to send the request from browser to Node.js server, and for the response to be transmitted back.
2. The HTTP request queue latency/depth

   ie. the time it takes from the Node.js receiving the HTTP request to the point that it can be handled. As Node.js has an event loop that runs on a single thread, only a single "blocking" action can be handled at a time. If the applications handling of the HTTP request is purely blocking as it is in the HelloWorld example (no asynchronous calls occur), then each HTTP request is handled in serial.

Its the second of these that's likely to be causing your delay - the HTTP requests are running in serial, so the Monitoring and Analytics service is telling you that it takes 111ms to build the response to the request, but there's an additional 800ms where the request is queued waiting to be run.

Comment: That makes sense. Is this officially documented somewhere?

Comment: I have requested that Chris' information be integrated into the product documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you don't have the network latency from client to server and server to client. 
Bluemix will record just the latency when it gets the call and when the response goes out. While with jMeter you are recording when the response will leave your computer and then when the response will come back (downloading the data as well).

900 ms is A LOT, I'm guessing how much data you receive with every single call.

Comment: The data returned is: "{'ret25':'ok'}". I think there is a test tool in bluemix. I will try to use that and test again.

Comment: 100 concurrent threads can be the cause to arrive at 900 milliseconds if you do some queries and calculations, but it is not possible that if you do just a return of that that it can go as high as 900 ms.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to suppose the issue is then in my side, I will investigate and post if I find the issue, thank you.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to remove the "Answer check". I think the overhead is not in my side. One request takes 80ms. In my home I'm running a test with 100threads and in other location far from my home the execution of one single thread (at the same time i'm running the 100threads test) takes 900ms. So I think this points that there is something in bluemix after Monitoring and Analytis adding that 800ms overhead.

Comment: It is ok by removing the check ;). Could we have the link to test as well? Because I still do not understand what you mean. doing a 100 thread, for how many times in total?, can make the latency higher, node maybe cannot keep up with everything and this is why it increases the latency it takes to respond

Comment: https://mainappnode.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/test. (https) The test is with jMeter, 100 parallel thread running during 30 minutes.

Comment: From my point of view, the problem is, as well your computer where you do the test. Because it has to handle the 100 requests at the time and downloading, sending and stuff and it is normal that it takes more than doing just one single call. Infact if you do 10 at the time it goes flawless.  Node, being single thread can have issues to handle loads of requests but for 100 parallel is not a very big deal.

Comment: With 100 concurrent threads the avg response time I get is 900ms but "Monitor and Analytics" show 111ms. If that 800ms overhed would be caused by my computer and my network, in other location someone executing a single request should get a response time of a bit more than 111 ms, but in that other location the response time is also 900ms.

Comment: When you gave me the link, i dont know if you were testing but with 10 threads i was gettin reaponses between 80 and 120

Comment: No, it is not running, I stopped it.